# Python - How to change letters like é

Tags: python, string, function, diacritics

Is there a function in python which converts letters like é to e, or í to i?

Comment: https://github.com/avian2/unidecode; read also this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net#comment23803622_249087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can filter and map the characters of a string through the following procedure:

```
from unicodedata import normalize, category

''.join([c for c in normalize('NFD',original) if category(c) != 'Mn'])
```

Here I filter these accents out of your *question*:

```
>>> original = 'Is there a function in python which converts letters like é to e, or í to i?'
>>> from unicodedata import normalize, category
>>> ''.join([c for c in normalize('NFD',original) if category(c) != 'Mn'])
'Is there a function in python which converts letters like e to e, or i to i?'
```